# Displaying links in XML to HTML XSL transform

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on transforming some XML into HTML via XSL and am having some trouble displaying links. The XML looks like this:

```
<c02 level="file">
    <did>
        <container type="Box">1</container>
        <container type="Folder">2</container>
        <unittitle>Folder A, </unittitle>
        <unitdate>2001</unitdate>
        <daogrp>
            <daoloc label="Image" href="www.test.com" role="Image/jpeg">
                <daodesc><p>Document</p>    
                </daodesc>
            </daoloc> 
        </daogrp>           
    </did>
    <scopecontent>
        <p>1 page</p>
    </scopecontent>
</c02>
```

My expected HTML is something like this:

```
<tr>
                    <td valign="top">1</td>
                    <td valign="top">2</td>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="10">Folder A, 2001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="8"><a href="www.test.com">Document<br />
                    </a></td>
```

and my XSL currently looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="daoloc">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@role='Image/jpeg'">
            <img src="{@href}" altrender="{@Document}"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@role='new'">
            <a href="{@href}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Document"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I've played around for a while with little success. How can I twist the XSL to get these links to display? Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Comment: Please show the expected result of the transformation. -- P.S. Your input - at least the part that you show us - has no element named `dao` - so your template is never applied and has no effect on the output.

Comment: The expected result is a hyperlink, displayed as "Digital Object" that points towards the href link. I've tried changing <dao> to both <daoloc> and <daogrp> in the template, and @show='new' to @role="image/jpeg", to no avail.

Comment: "*The expected result is a hyperlink, displayed as "Digital Object" that points towards the href link.*" That's not clear at all. Please edit your question and post the **exact** expected result **as code**.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="daoloc">
    <p>
        <a href="{@href}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </a>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

applied to your input (after adding a space between the `label` and `href` attributes!), will return:

```
<p>
   <a href="www.test.com">Document</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the link doesn't appear to be generating.

Comment: See it working here: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuu Are you getting a different result? With the same input?

Comment: I see. It works in isolation, but nothing happens when combined into the rest of my XML. I'll update the XML in the question for context.

Comment: It works with your updated XML, too. Of course, you need more templates to generate the other content from the other nodes.